# Mouseover Tooltip with css doesn't align correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to create a tooltip with css to span elements but when I do a mouseover it adds extra padding to original text. Is there a way to fix that?

Here's the code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmJqj

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

- `position: absolute;` on `span:before` and `span:after`

and

- `position: relative;` on `span`.

Like this:

```
span {
    color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}


span:hover:after{
    content: attr(data);
  dislpay: block;
  padding: .4em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: .4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.75em;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span:hover:before {
    display:block;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  border-right: .5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: .5em solid #333;
  border-left: .5em solid transparent;
  top: 1.25em;
  left: .5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it position absolute. The way you have it now, the content gets inserted as normal content:after. So it is in the normal flow and shifts the rest. When you put position:absolute to it, you take it out of the flow and can position it as liked.